# Why HTML form stopped working on large files?

Tags: php, forms, upload

I have created a upload form It's working fine while I am uploading small files. The html form is not working When I am trying to upload large files. Have you ever experienced this?

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: check your upload max size in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thank u so much for  your valuable comments..    I have cleared that by changing "post_max_size"  in Php.ini file.. In Default it was just 3 mb in my WAMP. I have changed it to 20Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on you php version, you could try something like:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '32M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '32M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```

just replace "32" with your desired maximum size.

Comment: Use -1 instead of 32 which means no limit. Note: Consider your RAM size as well when setting this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, PHP permits a maximum file upload of 2MB. You can ask users to resize their images before uploading but let’s face it: they won’t. Fortunately, we can increase the limit when necessary.

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Both can be set to, say, “10M” for 10 megabyte file sizes.

However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds).

These options can be set in your server’s `php.ini` configuration file so that they apply to all your applications.if you’re using Apache, you can configure the settings in your application’s `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Finally, you can define the constraints within your PHP application:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

PHP also provides a `set_time_limit()` function so you don’t need to set `max_execution_time` directly.

Setting the options in your PHP code is possibly more practical, since you can extend the execution time and increase the file size when your application is expecting a large upload. Other forms would revert to the default 30-second time-out and 2MB limit.